# Enabling Hardware-Assisted Virtualization on a Virtual Processor?

Tags: virtualization, hyper-v, vdi, windows-server-2012

I am currently trying to create a test-deployment of the new Remote Desktop Services in Server 2012. I have been following these instructions from technet: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh831585

I have installed Server 2012 and installed Hyper-V. I then created the 3 test machines as per the technet instructions. Everything went fine until I got to the actual deployment of the VDI Quick Start when I try to install the service on the APP1 machine I get an error saying it does not have support for hardware assisted virtualization.

Since I am running the server on Hyper-V is there anyway to enable hardware assisted virtualization on the virtual processor? Or am I just going to have to run VDI on a non-virtualized server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It CAN be done using ESXi as the top level hypervisor (also in the free version), eg http://www.virtuallyghetto.com/2011/07/how-to-enable-support-for-nested-64bit.html. This might not be what you wanted to hear...

Comment: absolutely correct, sucks but thats the way it is.

Comment: Yeah, I have done it in ESXi 5, but I was hoping to compare it to Hyper-V.